# My Bitcoin transaction timed out on CoinGate but payment/BC disappeared and merchant denies receiving it...how can I track it down?

Tags: blockchain, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions, tracking

So I sent a payment from my Blockchain wallet to a merchant late one night last week and found out in the morning it had "timed out" but the BC was gone and there was no option for a refund.  Naturally, I assumed the merchant had claimed the BC payment but they deny having received it.  CoinGate is not helping me figure out what happened, and I had copied and pasted the address from the CoinGate invoice so I don't see how it could have gone to the wrong address.

Coincidentally, the trail of the payment has it ending up in a wallet/account that the first payment I had made to this same merchant (which went through with no problem) also passed through.  The merchant says this is not an indication that they received the second payment and that the account through which both payments passed is likely a CoinGate account.  Here is the address that the payment that is MIA was sent to (copied and pasted from invoice in CoinGate):

36kHjTRjHLXKkyZa85VRKJqbswXi7vAZ1J

The BC amount:  0.05049452 BTC
217.16 USD @2018-11-30T05:36:16Z

This is the transaction ID:

93d7087f7e7f1fbca60ca3cb03eb65a43109876672e589664cf687d67113c5e4

The merchant has kindly agreed to ship my product despite not having received the payment.  We are hoping to be able to track it down through CoinGate, but so far they are less than helpful.  If anyone has insight into how to track this payment, I would greatly appreciate it.  Bitcoin is so widely used, I can't understand how it can just vanish in the midst of a transaction.  Makes me wary of using it ever again as I just spent the better part of 5 days trying to sort this out.

Comment: Your bitcoin did not vanish; that is not possible. Either Coingate or the merchant will have the coins, and they certainly should be able to deal with a situation of a timed-out payment request being confirmed (this 'time out' period is written into the payment gateway code, not the bitcoin network code). In any case, I'm voting to close this as off topic because it is a customer service issue.

Comment: The transaction is clearly here: https://longhorn.bullpay.com/?gateway=2&data=93d7087f7e7f1fbca60ca3cb03eb65a43109876672e589664cf687d67113c5e4 However, when asking questions like this i'd suggest "I sent money from my wallet (put wallet address here) to this wallet address (put wallet address here). I sent "this much", how do i prove it. That's agnostic and the answer would be the link above. The transaction exists on the blockchain, the proof is: it exists, it is in the wallet you were told to send it to. The options there are have the owner of the wallet return it, or honor the payment.